# Exporting 16 bit single-band to 8 bit in SAGA/QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, saga, raster-conversion, geotiff-tiff

Everytime with every function (e.g convert data storage type or gdal-translat -ot Byte) the output is a completely white map with a black border. only  the "save as" export works, but the TIFF also has 3 bands and the data is much bigger..this isnt my intention

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Show `gdalinfo -stats` reports from the original and converted. Put a sample image to play with somewhere for downloading if you have right to do it.

Comment: what is the range of your input values ?

Comment: value range of the input scene is 0 - 25480.812476
value range of the wrong created 8 bit is 0 - 255 enclosed u will find a link which contais the 16 bit single-band (free content):
http://www.file-upload.net/download-9541350/LC81940242014248LGN00_B5.TIF.html

Comment: Try adding `-scale src_min src_max` in gdal_translate code. `src_min` and `src_max` values based on yours 16bit raster value range will be needed to scale down to 8bit (see detailed description: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)

Comment: ive tried this and fortunatly the output has had the correct value range 0-255 + -ot byte command i have now the result i wanted to have. thanks!

Comment: Is there any possibility to do this process with SAGA, too? Additionally in SAGA there is no option to save raster with rendering, i think..

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @jzol I think your comment should be turned into an answer, as it solves the problem.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE! If you find a question or answer useful, please upvote it instead of using the answer form.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/94594)

Answer (score 4):

Lets have a close look at statistics about scene enclosed by you:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS Chugiak\bin>gdalinfo C:\Users\Janek\Desktop\LC819402420142
48LGN00_B5.TIF -stats

[...]

  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=65535 - this especially!

    STATISTICS_MEAN=10396.365071613

    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0 - and this one

    STATISTICS_STDDEV=7547.8323562457
```

... and histogram:

[image]

Having it's real values in much narrower range - to perform raster conversion you should force scaling in `gdal_translate`

Add `-scale src_min src_max` in gdal_translate code `src_min` and `src_max` values based on yours 16bit raster real value range, and `-ot Byte` to force 8bit value type. To omit no data areas add also `a_nodata 0`.

Try something like this:

[image]

Comment: What can be done if we have 3 bands with different min max values ?

Comment: You can alway process each band separately (for gdal_translate add flag -b to select given band e.g. -b 1) then you can merge bands back to a single raster (e.g. via vrt format or using gdalmerge)