# Exporting 16 bit single-band to 8 bit in SAGA

Tags: saga

Is there any possibility exporting 16 bit single-bands to 8 bit like in qgis (gdal_translate)? Additionally in SAGA there is no option to save raster with rendering, right?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question is related to yours previous: [Exporting 16 bit single-band to 8 bit in SAGA/QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114184/exporting-16-bit-single-band-to-8-bit-in-saga-qgis/114219?noredirect=1#comment162153_114219) so I'll answer using dataset you probably are working on (if not skip to step 3):

[image]

1. Bear in mind that *no data value* is wrong - black area is no data and values there are 0's

[image]

2. Set proper no data

[image]

3. After this preparation use `Convert data storage type` module (*Grid --> Values --> Convert data storage type*)

[image]

Resulting raster will loose this nice grayscale render due to huge narrowing the dispersion of the values after reducing from 16 to 8 bits.

Answering your second question: as far as I'm concerned in SAGA there is no option of exporting raster rendering.

Comment: what a pitty. there is no other module or option to write  commands like in qgis? if i convert 16 bit to 8 bit in qgis (gdal_translate) the result isnt a huge narrowing. i dont understand this discrepancy.