# how to convert this satellite image to RGB image

Tags: gdal, image

I have a `TIFF` file, looks like this:

```
**Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: quickbird2015.tif
       quickbird2015.tif.aux.xml
Size is 15106, 5106
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["unknown",
    DATUM["unknown",
        SPHEROID["unretrievable - using WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["foot",0.3048]]
Origin = (0.000000000000000,0.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (12.000000000000000,-12.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Lower Left  (       0.000,  -61272.000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,Invalid angle)
Upper Right (  181272.000,       0.000) (Invalid angle,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Lower Right (  181272.000,  -61272.000) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Center      (   90636.000,  -30636.000) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Band 1 Block=15106x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Red
  Min=0.000 Max=1600.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=1600.000, Mean=417.902, StdDev=84.773
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1600
    STATISTICS_MEAN=417.90197603601
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=84.772757670204
Band 2 Block=15106x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Green
  Min=0.000 Max=1756.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=1756.000, Mean=570.854, StdDev=114.902
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1756
    STATISTICS_MEAN=570.85403886609
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=114.90190934716
Band 3 Block=15106x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Blue
  Min=0.000 Max=1901.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=1901.000, Mean=356.139, StdDev=115.901
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1901
    STATISTICS_MEAN=356.13917758948
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=115.90136336507
Band 4 Block=15106x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=2151.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=2151.000, Mean=445.623, StdDev=158.418
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=2151
    STATISTICS_MEAN=445.62308850788
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=158.41828562429**
```

How can I convert this image to RGB?

Comment: If you downvote, please leave a comment, because it may not be clear to the OP.

Comment: I don't know why my question been downvoted. If I make something wrong, please leave a comment to let me now at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to achieve your desired result:

```
gdal_translate input.tif output.tif -b 1 -b 2 -b 3
```

Comment: Thanks for you anwser, I already tried it before I ask this question. But this output image is too dark and seems like not it's ture color.

Comment: How do you view the image? Since your image is 16 bit there may be a "wrong" histogram stretch used in your viewer. But you can also try converting it to 8 bit if you don't need the 16 bit depth for future processing. See this answer for details:https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/236291/68210