# How to display a bright and realistic GeoTIFF using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, merge, color, gdal-merge

I am using GDAL (gdal_merge) to put together some landsat photos using the proper bands.  When I open the GeoTIFF that is created using gdal_merge (in Windows), the GeoTIFF is super dark.  Now, when I open the same GeoTIFF in ArcMap, it's nice and bright and realistic looking.  I was wondering if there was a function in GDAL that would allow me to do what ArcMap is doing.
   I have tried using PIL (in python) to enhance the brightness, contrast, and color - and I have had some success, but certainly it's not as nice as what ArcMap is doing.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Just in case you are wondering, the gdal_merge command is as follows

```
gdal_merge.py -separate -ps 16 16 -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB -o "merged_new.tif" "LC08_L1TP_046029_20180717_20180717_01_RT_b4.tif" "LC08_L1TP_046029_20180717_20180717_01_RT_b3.tif" "LC08_L1TP_046029_20180717_20180717_01_RT_b2.tif"
```

But I don't think the gdal_merge command is an issue, as I am opening the result of gdal_merge with arcmap and it looks nice.

Comment: ArcMap automatically applies a stretch to your raster, I think the default for RGB is *percent clip*, if the resulting image is still detected to be dark a *gamma* is also applied... look at your symbology tab in ArcMap and note the settings. If you want to see the image *like it is in ArcMap* in a picture viewer you can export it *using renderer* to 'brighten up' the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ArcMap` stretches the values of a raster automatically by some clip algorithm (`percent clip`).

You can use `gdal_translate -scale` option to "scale"/stretch the values.

> **-scale [src_min src_max [dst_min dst_max]]:**
>       Rescale the input pixels values from the range src_min to src_max to the range dst_min to dst_max. If omitted the output range is 0 to 255. If omitted the input range is automatically computed from the source data.

So you need to find out the right values by yourself. Use `gdalinfo -hist merged_new.tif` to find see the values of the file.

Assuming most values (98%) lie between values of 20 and 150, we can do this:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -scale 20 150 0 255 merged_new.tif merged_new_scaled.tif
```

---

For your Landsat scene, you posted this information:

> Metadata: STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=35050 STATISTICS_MEAN=3832.5215314015 STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0 STATISTICS_STDDEV=4860.9555695374 Band 3 Block=9697x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Blue

That is a 16 Bit image. If you want an 8bit (=Byte) image to view it in an image viewer, you need to scale down the values with something like this `-ot Byte -scale 0 65535 0 255` to keep all values, or you can cut at the maximum: `-ot Byte -scale 0 35050 0 255`.

But that will probably still be too dark, as your mean is 3832 and stddev is 4860, so you might even want `-ot Byte -scale 0 16384 0 255`. As you will then cut some high values, you will lose information in very bright spots like clouds and glaciers.

---

**Related:**

- [Scale 16 bit to 8 bit within range using GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217743/scale-16-bit-to-8-bit-within-range-using-gdal)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and get back to the thread with results.  Is that true that 98% of values lie between 20 and 150 (as a general rule of thumb)?

Comment: No not at all.That is individual

Comment: Hmm...So using the command you referenced above, it creates a new tif, but the tif file is completely white.  
I ran the `gdalinfo -hist` command, and it gave me three sets of answers (I'm guessing one for each colorband).  There's a lot of info on the output, however.  What values from this output are the values that you are referencing in your answer?  Should I be looking here?
`Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=35050
    STATISTICS_MEAN=3832.5215314015
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=4860.9555695374
Band 3 Block=9697x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Blue
`
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *the tif file is completely white* ? The tif file has values not colors, the program you open the file with "decides" which value is which color. You need to scale the values to mach a "normal" 8 bit image, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the updated answer.  Although your numbers gave me a completely black picture, it put me on the right track.  

I used the following value "-ot Byte -scale 0 150 0 255", and it gave me a nice bright image.  You don't have to respond, as I've got what I need, but out of curiosity - do you know why that number worked?  If I go with a higher number, it starts to get darker and darker.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, do you know if there is a way to make the image more vibrant with color?  I think I have the -scale parameter down pretty well, but it looks fairly washed out now.  Thanks.

Comment: look into the `-exponent` option of [gdal_translate](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html). But you might be better off using an Image Editor ;-)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I need to do this via scripts.  The old one (using arcpy) seems to do it pretty easily.  I definitely can brighten up the image (using your suggestion with scale, as well as using the python PIL module), but the colors still seem washed out.  I will look into -exponent.  Thanks. :)

Comment: Can you expand on how/why a standard deviation of 4860 means a max scaling value of 16384 is appropriate?

Comment: @pLumo your exponent hint led me to wonder https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403776/what-is-the-gdal-translate-scale-exponent-option-for