# Converting from 16-bit TIFF image to 8-bit with GDAL does not work properly

Tags: gdal-translate

I am a beginner in the area of GIS and remote sensing image analysis. I am dealing with the satellite images from the **VNP46A1 Daily At-sensor TOA Nighttime Radiance Product. I want to get the TIFF images from the DNB_At_Sensor_Radiance_500m scientific dataset layer for further analysis.

I used the HDF to GeoTIFF convert script from NASA which I slightly changed. I need to reproject the images from the WGS84 to the S-JTSK coordinate system. The original arrays from which the images are produced contain UInt16 values. When I want to display the image, I got the black image. I need to convert them to the 8-bit images. In order to do this, I used the parameter `scaleParams` from `gdal.TranslateOptions`. However, I am still seeing the black image. Below is the part of the code that I used:

```
gdal.TranslateOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine(translateoptions), 
 format='GTiff', height=2400, width=2400, scaleParams=[[0, 65535, 0, 255]], resampleAlg=gdal.GRA_Bilinear, outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You scale the full range of int16 into full range of 8 bit. Think again and have a new try with `scaleParams=[[data_min, data_max, 0, 255]]`. Min and max of source data you can find with `gdalinfo -stats`.

Comment: You are right. Thank for your reply.

Comment: Write your solution as an answer.

Comment: I used the `np.min()` and `np.max()` functions to find the `data_min` and `data_max` from the arrays, and thus determine the appropriate range of UInt16 values.